# WinForms application profiling

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, profiler

We have a C# WinForms application that is quite slow and often consumes 50% CPU time.

By using DotTrace, we found out that the most time-consuming jobs are on the UI thread. 
Specifically, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message&) consumes most time.

I know that the program calls Invoke or BeginInvoke on DataGridView controls. That equals to sending a message to the DataGridView Control. But the time spent on the calling thread to send out those messages is quite small, the most time spent is on the UI thread to process those messages.

So dotTrace can figure out that the most time-consuming job is on the UI thread, but it cannot figure out which threads send out those messages.

So What I can do to find those threads?

Comment: "We have a C# Winform application that is quite slow. It often assumes 50% CPU time." - really ? if it were really slow I'd expect spikes much higher than that...Have you got some sort of "UI Update storm" happening? By that I mean, UI updates trigger other updates and cascade...

Comment: @MitchWheat Yeah, I used Windows Task Manager to monitor the program. The CPU usage is always around 50%. Actually, the program is a trading  platform. It continuously receives quote information, order status information, etc from outside, does some computation and then updates the UI. We're writing an auto-trading pragram so it issues around 100 orders every second. We found it cannot process all the incoming messages quickly. So we need to find out what is the bottleneck. If it is the UI, we need to find out what causes the UI update and may slow down the update frequency.

Comment: You may have a event in DataGridVew that have a long processes and/or that triggers multiple times or perhaps endlessly activating such as when cell value changes or row is added.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, which version? The profiling tools with VS2012 are mint and should provide all the detail you required to get to the bottom of your problem...

Comment: This is a standard mistake, DGV gets abused a lot like this.  Adding 100 rows a second to the grid is but a demonstration of "it works!"  No human ever stands a chance to actually look at it, 20 rows/sec is already a hopeless blur.  Compound the useless UI by also adding a single row at a time instead of chunks of rows and you'll bring the cpu down to its knees as well.  Do a usability study and you'll get the kind of feedback you need to create a *useful* UI.  The speed problem will automatically resolve itself as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for a windows application it is expected that wndproc will be the most called and time consuming method. It is the heart of an application that handles everything. When you hover over a control with the mouse, it's wndproc handler will be called for almost every pixel the mouse crosses, which is quite allot!

That said, the handling of these events should be efficiently written. Larger operations should be delayed by having a small shifting timeout after the last message before the actual operation starts. Retrieving the source of the messages is quite a difficult task since the sender of the messages cannot easily be retrieved (usually it is the OS, unless you call BeginInvoke excessively).

One handy tool that might give a hint is [SoftwareTrails](http://www.lovettsoftware.com/LovettSoftware/post/2012/09/07/Software-Trails.aspx). It provides a heat-map of recently used classes. Dock it to one side of the screen while clicking around in your app. You will probably see most activity in the System and Microsoft Namespaces, and less in your own. If not, check if you are handling MouseHover events or something.

It is totally normal for wndproc to be the most called routine in a windows app.

EDIT after reading the comments:

Looks like you are calling `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` quite allot, so look those methods up in your profiler and use the call-graph to see what's calling them. Not sure if DotTrace has a full callgraph though, it does have a call tree, but you will need a graph in order to see all the callers with thefrequencys they call your function. There are many profilers out there that include a call-graph.